# Reactjs instantiate a class

Tags: reactjs

I have a question about Reactjs classes.

It appears that Reactjs classes do not need to be instantiated.

`import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'

class Hello extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return &lt;h1&gt;Hello, {this.props.name}!&lt;/h1&gt;
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(&lt;Hello name=&quot;John&quot; /&gt;, document.getElementById('root'))`


The class Hello is never instantiated but the code works.

However in javascript (ES6) classes can be initiated 

`class Dog {
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.bark = 'Bow wow';
  }
sayName(){
    return this.name;
  }
bark(){
    return this.bark;
  }
}

// Instance of Dog class
const taro= new Dog('taro')`

Why do Reactjs classes not need instantiate when creating an object as in javascript?
Is not Reactjs a superset of javascript? 
Is it the compiler that does the instantiation?

Answer (score 1):

> Why do Reactjs classes not need instantiate when creating an object as in javascript?

They do get instantiated. You just don't see where they're done since it's abstracted behind JSX and React's APIs.

> Is it the compiler that does the instantiation?

No, it'd done inside React at runtime, inside [`React.createElement`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#createelement) to be precise. It eventually calls `constructClassInstance` which can be seen here: https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.14.0/umd/react-dom.development.js